# How to generate urls in Behat

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

I have started to test my Symfony2 application with the BehatBundle and MinkBundle. Now I am trying to write scenarios that check the response of some pages. These pages are accessible via an URL which contain the ID of the entities. Now I'm wondering how to know which ID was inserted by Doctrine.

Here's an example:

```
Background:
    Given There is no "Category" in database
      And I have a category "Todo Lists"

  Scenario: The category can be viewed
    Given I am on "/category/<id here>"
     Then I should see "Todo Lists"
```

The problem is I don't know how to find out the ID of the category inserted. Is that possible with Behat / Mink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a custom step into your context class, something like this:

```
/**
 * @Given /^I am on the "([^"]*)" category page$/
 * @When /^I go to the "([^"]*)" category page$/
 */
public function gotoCategoryPage($categoryName)
{
    // find category by $categoryName here
    // $category = ...

    $s = $this->getSession();
    $s->visit($this->locatePath('/category/'.$category->getId());
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I see it wasn't that hard after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `Given` statement with something like:

```
Given There is no "Category" in database
  And I have a category "Todo lists" with id "1"

Scenario: The category can be viewed
Given I am on "/category/1"
 Then I should see "Todo Lists"
```

And then set id for category as you do for name already.

Comment: Thanks, but the ID is auto-generated ... so there is no setter.